# git push to remote branch bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

I am running a build in bitbucket pipeline for a hotfix branch. On successful execution of step, I want the next step to push the branch to `develop` branch. 
I am trying to use the following command:

```
      - step:
          script:
            - git push "https://$bitbucket_username:$bitbucket_password@bitbucket.org/clinically/eregbinder-backend/branch/develop"
```

Which produces the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/clinically/eregbinder-backend/branch/feature/dev2/ERB-899-implement-feature-vs-release/': Port number ended with 'S'
```

Not sure if the password starting with "S" is related to the error message.

How can I push my branch to remote branch in my repo from within bitbucket build container?

Comment: Hint: [`git push` syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push): `git push $repository_URL_root $local_branch[:$remote_branch]`. Repository URL **root**, not repo+branch; branch(es) are provided seprately.

Comment: As for the error about port number: do `$bitbucket_username` or `$bitbucket_password` contain special (for URL syntax) characters? I suspect there is `@` somewhere. Please remember you must `%`-encode special characters.